# passing a generic type to a nested sealed class

Tags: generics, kotlin, inner-classes, sealed-class

Is it possible?
How can I expain to the compiler that its the same type (BR) extending the same class?
The code bellow fails

```
class BaseRepository<BR: BaseResponse>() {

sealed class BaseSealedResponse {
    open class Success(val receivedValue: BR)
    open class RequestError(val error: HttpException)
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Only [`inner` classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html#inner-classes) can refer to type parameters of the outer type. A `sealed` class cannot be marked as `inner`, so it can only access its own type parameters:

```
class BaseRepository<BR: BaseResponse>() {
    sealed class BaseSealedResponse {
        open class Success<B: BaseResponse>(val receivedValue: B)
        open class RequestError(val error: HttpException)
    }
}
```

You can define a member function inside `BaseRepository` that creates instances of `Success` parameterized with `BR`:

```
fun Success(receivedValue: BR) = BaseSealedResponse.Success(receivedValue)
```

Comment: You can declare the sealed class in the way I provided in the answer and then define a factory function inside `BaseRepository`: `fun Success(receivedValue: BR) = BaseSealedResponse.Success(receivedValue)`. This will let you directly create instances of `Success` parameterized with `BR`.

Comment: that really doesnt do the trick (  I guess you cannot combined sealed classes logic with generics (((

Comment: Parametrize `BaseSealedResponse<BR: BaseResponse>` and make sure it's only created with the same parameter inside `BaseRepository`.